# Why is this arithmetic combinator not working?

Tags: factorio

I set up an arithmetic combinator exactly as in [this video at 6:47](https://youtu.be/u6ryTThD9xs?t=417).  In the video, the combinator outputs the yellow with summed values.  In my Factorio pictures, there is no yellow output.

I'm using Factorio version 1.1.19.

How do I get the arithmetic combinator (or other signal network pieces) to sum its inputs and output a single number?  (What I actually want is to sum all the items on a belt, and activate an inserter if that sum is greater than some number.)

[image: arithmetic combinator]

[image: output signal]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have connected the wire from the constant combinator to the *output* side of the arithmetic combinator; you need to connect it to the input side instead (where the inward-pointing yellow arrow is). Which side the connection is made on depends on which half of the combinator's 2×1 shape you click on when connecting a wire.

How I can tell:

- The small electric pole you've highlighted, which definitely is connected to the output, is showing the input signals, indicating they're sharing a wire. When correctly connected, the input signals will *not* appear there (unless you run another red or green wire to the constant combinator).
- The line of the wire from the constant combinator is heading more towards the middle than the red input post of the arithmetic combinator.

  (Wiring is one of the rare places where it can be useful to view them with alt mode *off,* so the symbols are not obscuring the physical structures.)